# How Do I Get RuTube.ru To Play Videos?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

How can I play RuTube videos?

Here is the link to the site, its a Russian version of YouTube.

[RuTube](http://rutube.ru)

The videos on this site won't play using Chromium or Firefox browsers. They play on my phone using Chrome browser.

Answer (score 1):

Go to terminal and type:

`sudo apt install adobe-flashplugin`

Now, the videos will play.

Comment: You should accept your question as answered so it will be more useful for those with the same problem.